# htaccess RewriteRule with optional language switch

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've set up `htaccess RewriteRules` to rewrite e.g. `"domain.ext/en/page"` to `"domain.ext?lang=en&p=page"` which works as expected.

However, I want to make the language part optional, so `"domain.ext/page"` will also rewrite to `"domain.ext?lang=en&p=page"`.

Here's the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^domain.ext/.*$ [NC]

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^$              index.php?lang=en
RewriteRule ^(en|nl)/?$         index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(en|nl)/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?lang=$1&p=$2
```

So I'd like to add something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/][[NOT (en or nl)]]+)/?$           index.php?lang=en&p=$2
```

Comment: There was no answer that solves the problem. I've since changed my mind and no longer want to make the language string optional, so I have no need to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regex:

```
^(?!en|nl)([^/]+)/?$
```

to rewrite `"domain.ext/page"` will also rewrite to `index.php?lang=en&p=$2`.

You can also add:

```
^(?!en|nl)[a-z]{2}/([^/]+)/?$
```

to rewrite `jp/page/`, `fr/page/` to `index.php?lang=en&p=$2`

I hope that it helps you. Good luck :-)

Comment: Does not seem to work. "RewriteRule ^(en|nl)/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?lang=$1&p=$2" stops working.